# Enable Python in SQL Server 2017

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have executed below command:

```
 EXEC sp_configure 'external scripts enabled', 1
 RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
```

From message it looks like all success:

```
 Configuration option 'external scripts enabled' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
```

However, when executing below script, its showing error:

```
exec sp_execute_external_script 
@language =N'Python',
@script=N'OutputDataSet = InputDataSet
print("Input data is {0}".format(InputDataSet))', 
@input_data_1 = N'SELECT 1 as col'
```

Error:

```
   Msg 39023, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_execute_external_script, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 7]
 'sp_execute_external_script' is disabled on this instance of SQL Server. Use sp_configure 'external scripts enabled' to enable it.
```

When I executed  :  exec sp_configure

Its showing "external scripts enabled" run_value as 0

When I'm updating "run value" by running update query:

```
 update sys.configurations set value_in_use = 1
 where name like 'external scripts enabled'
```

Getting error:

```
  Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.
```

Here is System details (from SSMS help -> about):

```
  SQL Server Management Studio          15.0.18118.0
  Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools  15.0.1300.131
  Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)   10.0.17134.1
  Microsoft MSXML                       3.0 6.0 
  Microsoft Internet Explorer           9.11.17134.0
  Microsoft .NET Framework              4.0.30319.42000
  Operating System                      6.3.17134

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU14) (KB4484710) - 14.0.3076.1 (X64) 
Mar 12 2019 19:29:19 
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 10.0 <X64> (Build 17134: )
```

Also, tried to install SQL Server latest update from here (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56128).

Python got failed to installed.

How can I resolve this issue and run python on SQL Server 2017? Do I need to install any SQL Server service pack? Please suggest.
Thanks.

Comment: That isn't your SQL Server version, that's the version of SSMS; which is completely unrelated. Use `PRINT @@VERSION;` to get your SQL Server version.

Comment: Updated my question with SQL version.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check the folder "PYTHON_SERVICES" and its contents available in below path:

[DriveName]:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.[YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME]\PYTHON_SERVICES

2. If not exists, then please go through below link to get it installed:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/install/sql-machine-learning-services-windows-install?view=sql-server-2017
3. If the above folder exists, then you need to set the "external scripts enabled" value to 1 by running the sp_configure proc and then RESTART your SQL Server instance.
   3.1. Right click on your SQL Server and click "Restart".
4. After successful restart of your service check the configured value enabled/disabled:

select * from sys.sysconfigures where comment = 'Allows execution of external scripts'
go

the "value" column should be 1.

5. If the "value" column set to 1, then you are good to execute the external scripts, such as "R" or "Python" from SSMS.

try running below and see if both returning results without any errors:

```
 exec sp_execute_external_script
    @language=N'Python'
   , @script=N'
   print("Hello World")'
 go

exec sp_execute_external_script
   @language=N'R'
 , @script=N'print(R.version)'
 go
```

Comment: The formatting of those commands apparently matters. It errored for me until I reformatted them.

 exec sp_execute_external_script @language=N'Python', @script=N'print("Hello World")'
 go

exec sp_execute_external_script @language=N'R', @script=N'print(R.version)'
 go

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server 2017, after you have run `EXEC sp_configure 'external scripts enabled', 1
 RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE`, you need to restart the instance.